# How to push redux-form input value to array?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am creating a redux-form Wizard Form that collects several input values of the same type that should be stored in redux as an array. For context, the form is collecting a Number value representing the amount of weight lifted on each of several sets (typically 3 to 5 sets). For each exercise type, there should be an array stored, e.g.:

```
form: {
  workout: {
    values: {
      deadlifts: [150, 160, 170, 180],
      bench-press: [135, 155, 175],
      etc ...
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that submitting a value merely overwrites the previous value. I am not sure how to (1) initialize redux store values as arrays, and/or (2) push new values to those arrays.

Each exercise has a Wizard Form. The Wizard Form is made up of several WorkoutForm components. The Wizard Form passes relevant information regarding exercise name, number of sets, etc., to the WorkForms with `currentExercise`. `setIndex` is from the Wizard Form component's state and tracks the curret set.

WorkoutForm

```
const WorkoutForm = ({ currentExercise, setIndex, handleSubmit }) => {

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field 
        name={currentExercise.name} 
        type="number" 
        placeholder={`enter ${currentExercise.track}`} 
        component={renderField} 
        label="exercise" />
      <div>
        <button type="submit" className="next">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  ) 
}

WorkoutForm.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  currentExercise: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired, // such as 'deadlift'
    reps: PropTypes.array.isRequired, // reps for each set, such as [10,8,6,4]
    track: PropTypes.string.isRequired, // either 'weight' or 'reps'
  }).isRequired,
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'workout',              // <------ same form name
  destroyOnUnmount: false,     // <------ preserve form data
  validate
})(WorkoutForm)
```

RenderField

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, placeholder, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={placeholder} type={type} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default renderField
```

Comment: In your `handleSubmit` you should call an action, which will return submitted value with action type. Based on this action type in reducer you should add value in array somehow like this `deadlifts: [...state.deadlifts, value]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tentative solution. Thanks to elmeister for the inspiration.

Action Creator

```
function setExerciseData(exerciseName, value) {
  return {
    type: 'SET_EXERCISE_DATA',
    exerciseName,
    value,
  }
}

export function gatherFormData(exerciseName) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const form = getState().form;
    const value = form.workout.values[exerciseName];
    dispatch(setExerciseData(exerciseName, value))
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

function setExerciseData(state, exerciseName, value) {
  if (!state[exerciseName]) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, { [exerciseName]: [value]})
  } else {
    return update(state, {
      [exerciseName]: {$push: [value]}
    })
  }
}
```

The `gatherFormData` action is triggered on input submit. I'd be happy to entertain better solutions, if you have comments. Thanks!